# how to use session variable in javascript to get parameter value from one javascript page to another?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to get value from one js file to another i am able to do that using cookies but i need to do using sessions can anyone suggest me on this ..(this value i need is for login control)
here is my code..

*********Login.js********

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var assemblyCode;
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var name = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;


       // alert("cons:" + name);

        assmbylogin(name);

    });



         function assmbylogin(AssemblyName) {
           //  alert('hi');

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Varuna.asmx/assmbylogin",
                 data: "{'AssemblyName':' " + AssemblyName + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: false,
                 success: OnSuccess
             });


             function OnSuccess(data, status) {
               //  alert('hi');
                 var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                 var  assname, assemblynameArray = [];
                 for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                     assemblyCode = obj[i].AssemblyCode;
                     assname = obj[i].AssemblyName;
                     assemblynameArray.push(obj[i].AssemblyName);
                 }
                 alert(assemblyCode);
                 document.cookie = "" + assemblyCode + "; expires=Thu, 20 Aug 2016 12:00:00 UTC";

             }
  }
   });
```

*************health.js***********

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bloodsettings, pvthospsettings, diasettings, hospsettings;
    var bloodsettingsAssembly, hospsettingsAssembly, diapsettingsAssembly, pvthospsettingsAssembly;
    var statediacount, statebbcount, statephcount;




    var aseemblyCode = document.cookie;


    $("#health").hide();

    //health
    $("#hlt").click(function () {

        $("#bcHostel").hide();
        $("#education").hide();
        $('#groundwater').hide();
        $("#health").show();
        $("#barchart1").show();
        $("#barchart2").show();
        $("#barchart3").show();
        $("#barchart4").show();
        GetAssemblyDetails1();
        hospitalcategory();
        Hospitalcount();
        bloodbankscount();
        pvthospitalcount();
        diagnosticcenterscount();
       alert(aseemblyCode);

    });
});
```

in the above code am trying to get the assemblycode from login.js to health.js
(arcgis js api 3.17)